# the setPath issue of extjs4.2 when combining with asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, extjs, web-applications

I am new to extJS and met a serious problem described as follows:

I used the Sencha Architect to build my client-side UI. After finishing it, I copy the generated app folder and app.js to my asp.net mvc project(located in ROOT/Scripts/app and ROOT/Scripts/app.js), and I also copy some dependencies(exr-all.js .etc) from the SDK directory to ROOT/Scripts/extjs.I was using Ext.Loader.setPath() method in my ROOT/Scripts/app.js file to indicate the mapping from specific class name to the specific location, but It does not work.
In my asp.net mvc project, I have a controller class and the Index action method just return a View(ROOT/Views/RepairList/Index.cshtml) whose code is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>RepairList</title>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Scripts/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" /> 
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Scripts/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/extjs/ext-lang-zh_CN.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/app.js">

    
    </script>

    
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In my ROOT/Scripts/app.js, the code is as follows:

```js
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.Loader.setPath('repairList', '../../Scripts/app');

Ext.application({

    name:'RepairList',
    requires: [
        'Ext.Loader'
    ],
    models: [
        'LineChart',
        'RadarChart'
    ],
    stores: [
        'MenuStore',
        'LineChart',
        'RadarChart'
    ],
    views: [
        'MainEntry',
        'chartPanel'
    ],
    controllers: [
        'management',
        'forms',
        'Info',
        'content'
    ],
    name: 'repairList',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('repairList.view.MainEntry');
    }

});
```

I dont know why the setPath does not work. I think it is because the view file is in ROOT/Views/RepairList/Index.cshtml, while the app.js and the app directory is in ROOT/Scripts/app. Moreover, the name of my class generated in the sencha architect is repairlist.model.foo while now they were placed under Scripts folder instead of a directory named repairlist.
//the file is in the original repairlist/app/view/MainEntry.js file when creating in the sencha architect while now I copy it in the ROOT/Scripts/app/view/MainEntry.js

```js
Ext.define('repairList.view.MainEntry', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    alias: 'widget.fillerentry',

    requires: [
        'repairList.view.headerPanel',
        'repairList.view.treeMenu',
        'repairList.view.contentPanel',
        'Ext.tree.Panel',
        'Ext.tab.Panel'
    ],

    margin: 0,

    layout: {
        type: 'border',
        padding: 0
    },

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'repairheader',
                    region: 'north'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'repairtree',
                    region: 'west'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'repaircontent',
                    region: 'center'
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

![enter image description here][1]
￼

the error message is as follows
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:27845/app/view/MainEntry.js?_dc=1434385119180 ......
![enter image description here][2]

could anyone tell me why this does not work? Thanks very much

Comment: Was this question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:
1 - You have set the name config in your application twice.
2 - When using Ext.application set your paths in the paths config.

```
Ext.application({

    name: 'repairList',
    paths : {
        'repairList' : '../../Scripts/app'
    },

    //...

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('repairList.view.MainEntry');
    }

});
```